# Comparative and Superlative for little?

Tags: comparatives, superlative-degree

What is the comparative and superlative for little?

Comment: It depends. Are you speaking of an amount (little money), or a size (little girl)?

Comment: If 'little' is about number (like amount of money) then it goes: little, less, least. If about size, there are two options, more formal is that you switch to 'small': little, smaller, smallest. Informally it is: little, littler, littlest. 'More little'' and 'most little' are formal and old fashioned to me. I'd make an answer out of this but ngrams is difficult to navigate for this ('littler' is a common surname).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had considered this idea as well.

However less and least refer to quantity rather than size.

Superlative - The littlest

Comparative - Less than (used very infrequently. It would be more appropriate to choose a variant of the word 'little' based on its use)

Comment: Smaller and bigger are more commonly seen. More little (or worse, littler) just doesn't quite work.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. They are much more natural. Please disregard. It's actually an interesting question.

Comment: *Littler* and *littlest* are certainly far less common than you'd expect given how frequent *little* is, though I wouldn't go so far as to call them grammatically incorrect.  *Smaller* and *smallest* are good substitutes in this sense.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as @Jonenealaska says, if it is money then *less* and *least* apply. In the case of 'girl' *littler* and *littlest*, whilst grammatically correct are less often used than *smaller, smallest*.

But if you were talking about crabs you were catching in a net off the pier then I don't see much wrong with *littler* and *littlest*.

Comment: WS, I'm not sure I agree that (for humans) little is less polite -- it's pretty normal to say "she's the littlest girl" or maybe "she's even littler!" You're right that it's "a bit impolite" but I suggest, it's exactly as impolite as "she's the smallest girl."  (Normally, particularly in the US, this would only be said with layers and layers of euphemism... "well considering height measures we'd say that Juliette has the most minimal value on that ..." sort of thing.) Indeed wouldn't you say that "little" is more "cute" than "small"?

Comment: @Fattie Good point. You are right. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that the comparative and superlative for the word 'little' are: 'less' and 'least' respectively. If we want to compare  inanimate things like dolls, can we  say something like:

> "My barbie doll is the littlest of all my dolls"

or

> " My barbie doll is the littler of the two dolls".

?

Comment: Using "of the two" in a sentence with a comparative is certainly incorrect - it is tautology.

Comment: *Less* and *least* don't specify size the way *littler* (or *smaller*) and *littlest* (or *smallest*) do.

Answer (score -3):

I disagree with most of these answers. "Little" is an absolute - like the word "unique". It cannot be qualified. "Littlest" is a word rather like the phrase "curiouser and curiouser", in that it is a sort of verbal joke. I have never heard littler. As a test try saying "She is more little (littler) than her sister." It sounds ridiculous. One has to use words like "small" in this context.

Comment: _Small_ and _little_ mean the exact same thing in this context. _Little_ is not semantically unable to express degrees, the regular comparative and superlative forms are just not used. The comparison with _unique_ is utterly flawed.

Comment: @Janus *Littler* and *littlest* are not extinct - it is just that they are less-often used.

Comment: @WS2 Yes, I should have said the non-suppletive comparative and superlative of _little_ are not **generally** used.